# Serverless WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I'm running sls deploy and getting the following warning that spams many lines.

```
Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime
Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime
Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime
Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime
Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime
...
```

What is the cause of this warning, should I be concerned? How do I fix it?

(If I need to add extra information to this question, please let me know and I'll edit the question right away).

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Not really I still get the same error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm having the same issue in the following scenario:

Serverless + Webpack + Babel

In recommended webpack config, dev-dependencies are excluded. Babel-runtime (depends of babel, normally added as dev-dependency) is a dev-dependency too.

If you add babel-runtime to your common dependecies, now serverless (using webpack) will package babel-runtime with full information about the package (in this case, the version required).

```
yarn add babel-runtime
```

or

```
npm i babel-runtime
```

You can avoid these warnings.

Comment: Wow good find, going to test this first thing in the morning!

Comment: The npm command should be 'npm i babel-runtime'. It does not allow me to submit edit.

Comment: I had to do `npm update` after running `npm i xxx` else serverless failed to deploy

Answer (score 0):

If the warning isn't causing an issue I always regret trying to fix up npm as you always end up down a time wasting rabbit hole of conflicting versions and broken serverless deployments.