# serverless framework - babel-runtime warnings

Tags: javascript, babeljs, serverless-framework

I'm using the serverless framework with the serverless-webpack plugin, and whenever I run sls deploy, I'm getting the following warning in yellow:

*Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime*

*Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime*

*Serverless: WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime*

Does anyone know how to handle these? I coulnd't find any information about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code so we can see what might be the issue?

Comment: I have recently posted a solution there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404025/serverless-warning-could-not-determine-version-of-module-babel-runtime/48469862#48469862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serverless WARNING: Could not determine version of module babel-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404025/serverless-warning-could-not-determine-version-of-module-babel-runtime)

Comment: I encountered this issue when using the NPM "middy-redis" package; unfortunately @Gonzalo 's solution did not work..

Comment: Have you tried to mark your library explicitly in "dependencies" section of package.json and rebuilding your lock file from scratch (yarn.lock / package-lock.json)?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to have the following in my .babelrc

```
     "transform-runtime":{
          "corejs": false,
        },
```

You can also play around with these options:

```
     "transform-runtime":{
          "absoluteRuntime": false,
          "corejs": false,
          "helpers": true,
          "regenerator": true,
          "useESModules": false
 },
```